# Al introducir por consola un numero separado por un punto (ej: 1.80) me lanza un error

Tags: java, scanner

Partiendo del siguiente codigo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DoWhile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        Boolean salir = false;

       do{

        System.out.println("Tu altura");

        Double peso = entrada.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(peso);

        salir = true;

       }while(salir == false);

        entrada.close();

    }
}
```

Cuando me pide la altura pongo: 1.80 y me tira el siguiente error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

```
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at DoWhile.main(DoWhile.java:16)
```

Si escribo 1,80 o 180 el programa continua con normalidad. ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: creo que tiene que ver con el idioma de tu teclado ,el cual debe estar como ENG debiendo ser ESP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso te recomiendo obtener la entrada como String, realizar un replace() en caso de ingresar "." y convertir a Double el valor

```
String input = entrada.nextLine().replace(".", ",");
Double peso = Double.parseDouble(input);
```